# Is there a difference between "git add . " and "git add -A"?

Tags: git, github, command-line

[screenshot from TheOdinProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxdY.png)

please see the scrnsht
i new to this new
it says using `git add .a` is for adding all files in **CURRENT DIRECTORY**
and `git add -A` is for adding all files in **CURRENT REPOSITORY**.
*Is directory different from repository or ONE AND THE SAME?Thanks.*

Comment: "Current Directory" is just the folder you're currently in. If you're at the root, then this would be the same as "Current Repository". If you `cd FOLDER`, then they would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **REPOSITORY** word is used to define the whole scope of your project. It's the folder where you can find the `.git` hidden folder, if you are using Git to the version control system.

Instead, a **DIRECTORY** is just a generic folder, that can be including a repository of some project.

In your example, using `git add .`, you will be adding all the files on the current folder, but if you use `git add -A`, you will be adding all the files from the whole project folder.

Hope to be useful :)